# exception rise with FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I wrote small app for monitoring file for changes.
When I run it, every time I get exception about Path. And I can't understand why. The path is really exist.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Run();
        }

        public static void Run()
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = @"D:\test\1.txt";
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

            watcher.Changed +=new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

static void  watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ChangeType);
}


    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact exception you get? Use a try/catch block to make it a little nicer to debug.

Answer (score 1):

FileSystemWatcher.Path should be a Path not a file name

```
watcher.Path = @"D:\test"; 
watcher.Filter = "1.txt";

private static void watcher_Changed(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // this test is unnecessary if you plan to monitor only this file and
    // have used the proper constructor or the filter property
    if(e.Name == "1.txt")
    {
         WatcherChangeTypes wct = e.ChangeType;
         Console.WriteLine("File {0} {1}", e.FullPath, wct.ToString());
    }
}
```

You can also limit the monitoring using the constructor that takes two parameters, the path and a file filter.

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"d:\test", "1.txt");
```

[See MSDN References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.path.aspx)

Comment: Yes! I had add try, catch block, and understood why I getting error.
But how can I set not folder, but directly file name?

Comment: You could still use the filter to monitor a specific file

Comment: You can limit the monitoring using the constructor that takes two arguments. The path to monitor and a file filter that could be also the file name to monitor

Comment: @Erno, yes, I have written the comment but was still testing.